# \label command appears within the text?

Tags: pdftex, labels

I have a problem with the \label command, it is supposed only to label your section without appearing withing the text. and in my case I want to label a section but it appears right after the section like in the picture. Is there any package to make it disapear ?

Thanks for your help
Omer[image]

Comment: you have presumably loaded the showkeys package

Comment: Exact thanks David. :)

Comment: don't add commands to the preamble unless you know what they are doing... half the questions here wouldn't be asked if people started from an empty preamble rather than a "template" full of dozens of unneeded packages.

Comment: You are right, tell me I have another question, the command \graphicpath does not work do yu have any idea from where could it come from ? Thank you @DavidCarlisle

Comment: well I know where it came from, as I wrote it, but what does "does not work" mean? in any case it is unrelated to this question so make an example that shows an error and post a new question if need be.

Comment: it should be `\graphicspath` (with an s) and comes from the graphicx package.